# starting Android fragment gives error 'android.transition.Transition',

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I found that this is a bug with android support package v4. I can not handle my problem. I tried changing to normal package instead of support package. But it still gives an error.

This is how I start my fragments. Sometimes it works if I close my activity and restart for the second time and if I switch between fragments it gives error in logcat as below and shows and empty grey fragment. I used add and replace but nothing changed.

```
public void startFragment(Fragment fragment, Bundle args, boolean willReplace) {
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        Fragment currentFragment = fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.msgFragContainer);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fManager.beginTransaction();
        //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_enter, R.anim.fragment_exit, R.anim.fragment_pop_enter, R.anim.fragment_pop_exit);
        //ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        if(!willReplace){
            if(fragment.isAdded()){
                ft.show(fragment);
            } else {
                ft.add(R.id.msgFragContainer, fragment, fragment.toString());
            }

            ft.hide(currentFragment);
        }else{
            ft.replace(R.id.msgFragContainer, fragment, fragment.toString());
        }
        if(fragment.toString() != null)
            ft.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
        ft.commit();
    }
```

My logcat:

```
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.addTargets
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.addTransitionTargets
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.beginDelayedTransition
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.captureExitingViews
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.cleanupTransitions
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.cloneTransition
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.excludeTarget
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.mergeTransitions
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.removeTargets
Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setEpicenter
Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$3', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setSharedElementEpicenter
```

Comment: Seems very similar to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77670, check that and see if it helps.

Comment: I read that all. Everybody there was looking a solution for that. and I could not get any answer from there

Comment: What is 'fManager'? Is it 'getFragmentManager()' or 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

Answer (score 0):

I updated the library appcompat_v7 to  23.0.1 version